# How to Fetch Data from .ICS file in Sharepoint 2010 ?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, xslt-list-view-web-part

How to fetch data from iCalendar file in sharepoint 2010 webpart ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a WebPart that will read data from a iCalendar file using a third party .Net assembly, I personally didn't used them before but here's the two of them I can think of right now,

[DDay.iCal](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/)

and

[icalparser you can also use it to parse ICS file to text and then read it but its up 2 you](http://sourceforge.net/projects/icalparser/)

For more information check these links out

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498938/parser-for-ics-files-in-net

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635657/is-there-a-good-library-in-net-for-parsing-displaying-ics-feeds

Hope this helped :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. but DDay.iCal file have no strong name.. I tried to geerate .snk File using cmd. but not registered in GAC. So It is not working for me.. Do you know how to register dll to GAC?

Comment: Did you put DDay.iCal dll file to gac and did a IIS reset ? and also did you referenced proper version of it, like if you downloaded 64 bit your development machine should be 64 bit as well